# Depth video quality much lower than frames

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib, kinect

I am using Microsoft Kinect v2 to record depth frames. I am saving the frames as numpy arrays in my laptop for recording portability. Since the laptop isn't much powerful, I am then using a capable desktop in my lab to create a depth video for every recording. I am using python3 for this task. 
While I am able to create the video, the video quality is super bad. But when load and see individual frames as an image, the quality is much better. I have done pixel value normalization in both cases. Please help with how to proceed with this.

[Link to sample frame numpy array. (BTW it is 424x512)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GKuEjZXyI7UWqaBxaEDeb05gpLkYXNOQ)

Code for pic 1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
# plt.plot("1.npy")
# plt.show()
ape = np.load("depth_files/0.npy")
ape = ape/np.max(ape) * 255
ape = ape.astype(int)
plt.imshow(ape,cmap='gray',vmin=0,vmax=255)
plt.show()
```

[single separate frame image (GOOD QUALITY) - code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Dx9.jpg)

Code for pic 2:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from pykinect2 import PyKinectV2
from pykinect2.PyKinectV2 import *
from pykinect2 import PyKinectRuntime

# print(next(os.walk(os.getcwd()+"/depth_files/"))[1])

list_of_dir, a = next(os.walk(os.getcwd()+"/depth_files"))[1],next(os.walk(os.getcwd()+"/depth_files"))[2]
# print(a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i]=int(a[i][0:len(a[i])-4])

_kinect = PyKinectRuntime.PyKinectRuntime( PyKinectV2.FrameSourceTypes_Depth)

codex = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG')
dank_path = "video"
if(dank_path in list_of_dir):
    pass
else:
    os.mkdir("depth_files/"+dank_path)
print((_kinect.depth_frame_desc.Height, _kinect.depth_frame_desc.Width))
a=np.sort(a[0:len(a)-1])
# print(a)
depth_video = cv2.VideoWriter('depth_files/video/depth.avi',codex,24,(_kinect.depth_frame_desc.Width,_kinect.depth_frame_desc.Height),0)
for j in a:
    apple = np.load("depth_files/"+str(j)+".npy")
    apple = (apple/np.max(apple))*255
    apple = apple.astype(int)
    depth_video.write(apple)

depth_video.release()
```

[frame image form video (BAD QUALTY) - code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVd1C.jpg)

**I DON'T WANT FIRST TO CREATE IMAGES AND THEN VIDEO AS I NEED PROCESS A HUGE DATA.**
**I ALSO DON'T WANT TO CHANGE LANGUAGE FROM PYTHON TO JAVA/C++.**

Comment: It's probably not happy about being fed an array of 32bit signed integers as an image. I'd try `apple = apple.astype(int)` -> `apple = apple.astype(np.uint8)` | Sidenote: Variable names like `apple`, `ape`, `dank_path`  certainly don't help you in understanding the code.

Comment: if you want to save depth frames for later usage, you maybe shouldn't reduce the bitrate of the images (depends on your task).

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks a lot.